# Angular2 RC2 404 GET /browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.12.5.js

Tags: typescript, angular

After switching to RC2 I am getting an error

```
404 GET /browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.12.5.js
```

I didn't reference it in index.html.

I searched the whole root folder including generated .js files. Nowhere referenced it.

Here is my package

```
{
  "name": "TestApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\"",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

So where did that `browser-sync-client.2.12.5.js` reference come from and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

browser-sync is referenced by `lite-server` to livereload changes. delete lite-server from node_modules and npm install again. Might as well nuke whole node_modules folder

Comment: i do need lite-server to load changes though. Does deleting lite-server from node_module make lite-server become invalid?

Comment: do you mean reinstall lite-server?

Comment: Yes, clear node_modules folder and npm install again

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem, tried the above solution but it didn't resolve. Is there any other way to solve.